# Python get all final values from nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary for example:

`nested_dict = {'a':{1:2, 4:5}, 3:{'b':{'c':'d'}}, 'e':5}`

I'm trying to find a way to get the leaf values of the nested dictionary. So in the example I shared the final values are `[2,5,'d',5]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some recursion will be needed. Here is a generator example:

```
def all_vals(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for v in obj.values():
            yield from all_vals(v)
    else:
        yield obj

>>> list(all_vals(nested_dict))
[2, 5, 'd', 5]
```

Comment: this is admittedly much nicer than my version...

Comment: *blushes Thank you =) Still good to show different paradigms

Answer (score 2):

you could use this recursive function (with  `result` as an accumulator):

```
nested_dict = {'a': {1: 2, 4: 5}, 3: {'b': {'c': 'd'}}, 'e': 5}


def get_values(data, result):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            get_values(item, result)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for item in data.values():
            get_values(item, result)
    else:
        result.append(data)


result = []
get_values(nested_dict, result)
print(result)  # [2, 5, 'd', 5]
```

testing for `list` is not necessary as i see in your example... but this way the function should work for JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function that checks for the type of the values in the dictionary.

```
def print_leafs(dictionary):
    for value in dictionary.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print_leafs(value) #recursive call
        else:
            print(value)
            
nested_dict = {'a':{1:2, 4:5}, 3:{'b':{'c':'d'}}, 'e':5}

print_leafs(nested_dict)
```

the output is

```
2
5
d
5
```

You can `yield value` instead of `print(value)` if you want. You will have to modify the function to include a `yield from` statement for the recursive call (similar to @user2390182 answer):

```
def print_leafs(dictionary):
    for value in dictionary.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from print_leafs(value) #recursive call
        else:
            yield value
```

Comment: If you do swap print for yield, you will have to handle the recursive call differently

Comment: True, you should also `yield from print_leafs(value)` I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
def extract_leaves(possible_dict):
    if isinstance(possible_dict, dict):
        for key in possible_dict:
            extract_leaves(possible_dict[key])
    else:
        print(possible_dict)

extract_leaves(nested_dict)
```

Output:

```
2
5
d
5
```